# Spring Boot puts Request in Queue and waits for other request to finish first

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have an Application in `Spring Boot`, when i load a webpage it hits a service and gets the result from it. Response takes some time about (10-15) seconds because of searching in database. So if i close that webpage and open another instance of same page the Spring Boot puts that request in a queue and waits for 1st request to finish even if i have closed that webpage. Also if so many requests are in Queue tomcat server is crashed.

What i have done so far is i have modified tomcat threads in `application.properties` as

```
server.tomcat.max-threads=20
```

So is there anyway i can make it multi threaded ?

`Note : The number of requests can be more than 20 also`

**I am using Spring Boot 1.5.2 for this application**

**EDIT :**
I also have One similar application running in `Spring boot 2` and that application does not have this type of issue. Application Logic is almost same for both but Second Application Queries take a bit less time.

Comment: Which spring boot version you are using?

Comment: @AmmarAli its 1.5.2

Comment: Tomcat is multithreaded. You are actually decreasing the number of threads by setting it to 20 as the default is 200. There is no queuing in tomcat so nothing is being put in a queue. The fact that you percieve something like that doesn't mean it is. Check your database and make sure that you aren't leaking connections or have enough connections available, the default poolsize is 10. So if you have more then 10 requests it might be that one needs to wait.

Comment: @M.Deinum i agree with you that i have limited it to 20 but if i dont limit it after some requests the server is crashed. and thanks i will check my database

Comment: @M.Deinum I also want to let you know that I have similar type of application which is running in Spring boot 2 and that does'nt have this issue. Logic behind both application is same

Comment: Regardless. You have limited the capacity of tomcat to 10% of what it normally handles. If your pages are different with a bit of luck you have 6 requests, and t hus threads, occupied for 1 page, after 3 pages your rendering will stop because there is no more room to handle the requests.

Comment: Also closing a browser doesn't make the request unsend. The request has been fired regardless of the state of browser/device. The server only sees the rquest and doesn't know anything (nor assumes anything) about the state of the client.

Comment: Also I have to rephrase my comment, there is some queuing possible in tomcat but that is highly unlike to kick in with the default 200 available threads.

Comment: @M.Deinum fair point. If there's any way to stop the request i can also do that because i will know when the tab is closed, but unfortunately we cant do that. Also rendering is not a problem for us, we are only concerned with our tomcat crashing

Comment: You cannot unsend a request hence that is simply not possible. Rendering might be the cause of all this, as each reference/file/js/image is retrieved by another request, max. 6 per page (generally speaking). Nonetheless why are you crippling tomcat by reducing the number of threads.

Comment: @M.Deinum what if we close the requests from browser like cancel the requests manually. and `as you said closing a browser doesn't make the request unsend.` is there a way to tell the server don't continue this specific request while i already cancel the request from front-end manually.

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: Use connection pooling

Comment: @M.Deinum the actuall issue we are facing is when we hit same service multiple times at same time. it acquires db connections and start query process and you can say query is a little bit complex and we already optimize it in multiple chunks but still ne query is taking so much time and after hitting service multiple times cpu usage reached at 250% and db gets down.
during running this test we remove the max-threads from application.propertiest mean spring boot was using default max-threads value which is 200.

Comment: Then use for this piece of your application async processing (and no I don't mean `@Async` but async request processing). That way you can have a seperate thread pool for executing this long running query (incl. queuing) and still have tomcat responsive for the other parts of your application).

Comment: ok let me try with this like async request processing. thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

A better design would mean a service with two endpoints:

1. A POST URL that allows the user to send a request to the server and get a key token back.  The server puts the message on the queue and returns the token.
2. A GET URL that allows the user to send the token and either get the response back or nothing if it's not back from the queue.

You should register a pool of listeners that take the requests off the queue and put them in a database (key token/value pair).  When the user sends a GET request for their token, the server side looks it up in the database and returns the result.

If your database search takes 10-15 seconds you should think about speeding that up.  Do you have appropriate indexes?  Partitions?  Is this a relational database?

Comment: this approach seems better but it will still use same processing power when we send 1st POST request it will do all processing and save results somewhere but when we do get result it only sends the request so we save no resource at the end. And yes we have indexed our database still we have some complex joins which cause searching slow and we use MySQL db which is relational

Comment: The benefits are improved user experience and thread clean up.  I’d run EXPLAIN PLAN on those queries. They are far from optimal.  I’d bet you have a table scan going on.